# Tibco Connection error while connection Oracle 10g Express Edition

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, tibco

I am trying to connect to Oracle Database 10g Express Edition. While connecting am getting the error as

> BW-JDBC-100033 "Configuration Test Failed. Failed to find or load the JDBC driver: tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oracle.OracleDriver"

Can anyone please help me on this issue?

Comment: It may help to post a detailed description of how you are connecting.  It looks like you are using JDBC so you may want to post your code, where your JDBC driver jar is,etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of TRA are you using? Be aware that from TRA 5.7.0 onwards, the DataDirect drivers (such as `tibcosoftwareinc.jdbc.oracle.OracleDriver`) are no longer shipped with the product. If that is your case, you have 2 options:

1. Download the TIBCO Database Drivers Supplement, which includes the DataDirect drivers.
2. Download the Oracle JDBC driver, drop the appropriate ojdbc jar in the `<TIBCO_HOME>/tpcl/5.x/jdbc` folder (create the folder if it doesn't exist) and use the `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` reference in your BW project.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, 
Thanks for your answer but still am getting same error, i am using"TIB_tra_5.7.1" version can you please suggest.

Comment: Vinay, did you go with option 1 or 2?

Comment: Nicolas thank you very much now its working fine..:) and plese suggest how to learn tibco am begineer..